# How to deploy rails app in jboss server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, jboss5.x

Does anyone have knowledge about this , as I have referred some of the document but they are outdated links are below

http://www.railsinside.com/deployment/156-jboss-on-rails-deploying-rails-apps-to-a-jboss-app-server.html

https://github.com/bobmcwhirter/jboss-rails/tree/master

can anyone help on this